# How google found that the request is tampered or being interrupted

Tags: security

I started fiddler and when I tried to access google.com , I got the below error

[image]

It was able to find that, the request is coming from an untrusted tool or something like that. Can anyone please explain how they are doing it or any hint about it, so that, we could apply for our web sites.

Once I closed the fiddler, it started working fine again.

Thanks in advance
Jonathon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained in the "what does it mean" section: Fiddler has send your browser its own SSL certificate to be able to intercept the request (it –more or less– decrypts it using its certificate, then re-encrypts it using Google's one).

Chrome comes preloaded with public keys that it expects to see in the certificate chain for web sites, including of course google.* ones, so it can detect that Fiddler's certificate is not one coming from Google.

See http://blog.stalkr.net/2011/08/hsts-preloading-public-key-pinning-and.html